# What could possibly cause "Request has been truncated" on ajax request

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I have a contact form with file upload function. I am testing with 1 small image 500kb and standart fields /names, email, phone and etc../ and getting error:
"Request has been truncated"
My code is:

```
if(errors < 1){
form_data.append('fname', fname);
form_data.append('name', name);
form_data.append('mail', mail);
form_data.append('phone', phone);
form_data.append('subject', subject);
form_data.append('message', message);
form_data.append("filetoup", filetoup);

$.ajax({
method: 'post',
url: "/ajax/contactus.php",
async: false,
dataType: "json",
contentType: false,
cache: false,
async: false,
processData: false,
data: form_data,
beforeSend:function(){
 $('#global-loader span').html('<br /><label class="text-primary">' + 'Working..' + '</label>');
},
success: function(data){
$('.msg').html(data[0]);
 $('html, body').animate({scrollTop: $('.msg').offset().top - 150}, 800);
$('#global-loader').hide();
        }
    });
    return false;
}
```

Thank you for any ideas

Answer (score 0):

Such errors usually happen to me in assignments that do not match the format you set (possibly when there is data that needs more fields than the defined field). For example, you have a 30 character column in the database and you encounter this error when you want to write 50 characters of data in that column.

Comment: but in this case database is not involved at all.. I don't save the form data also I dont query any information needed for the form..